# Embedding trees of diameter four is NP-hard

Tags: graphs, np-complete

Suppose that $T$ is a tree of diameter four and $G$ is a graph. Deciding, whether $T$ can be injectively mapped to $G$ is NP-hard (there is a simple reduction from the problem of finding an independent set). I want to use this result as a side remark in my Bachelor's thesis. I believe that this should be a well-known problem, though I was not able to google it. Do you know some relevant literature to this?

Comment: If the reduction is simple, it's faster to just write it down than to look for a reference. Have you checked in Garey & Johnson?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I checked and it is very probably not there. Although the reduction is simple, I think that the author (if there is any) should be cited. :-)

Comment: Could you give more detail on what you mean by "injectively mapped"?  This clearly means that distinct vertices in $T$ should map to distinct vertices in $G$, but it's not clear how edges map.  I see 4 possibilities, formed by taking the template "There is an ____ in $G$ between $f(u)$ and $f(v)$ if ____ there is an edge in $T$ between $u$ and $v$" and replacing the first ____ with either "edge" or "path", and replacing the second ____ with either nothing or "and only if".

Comment: In case you mean the version with "edge" and "if and only if", there's a simple reduction from independent set to the version of your problem where $T$ has diameter 2 -- just add another vertex that is adjacent to all existing vertices, and make $T$ a $k$-leaf star.

Answer (score 1):

It is reducible from **Independent Set in cubic graphs**.

Given a cubic graph $G(V,E)$, construct a bipartite graph $\mathcal{B}(V\dot{\cup}E,\mathcal{E})$, where $$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{E})=\{(u,e)|u\in V\ \mathrm{is\ incident\ to}\ e\in E\}$$

Create a new vertex $r$ (the root), connect it to all $V$-vertices in $\mathcal{B}$.

Now, if the IS instance asks for an independent set of size $k$, we create $T$ of diameter $4$ as follows:

Make a new vertex $r_T$ as root of $T$. This vertex would have $k$ children. Each of these $k$ children would have $3$ leaves attached to it.

Our reduction then outputs the instance $\mathcal{B},T$ of $\mathrm{TREE\ EMBEDDING}$ problem.

Note that $k>10^9$, otherwise the vertex cover can be decided in polynomial time. So, if there exists an embedding, $r_T$ must be mapped to $r$.

Since all the leaves are pairwise distinct. The image set of $k$ children of $r_T$ is the independent set.

Comment: What's the magic with $10^9$?

Comment: as the next sentence claims there, $k$ should be large enough to force $r_T$ being mapped to $r$ solely by large (and unique) degree. $k>5$ is enough in fact.